# переменные окружения для docker-compose+symfony4+mysql

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose

Не могу понять, как убрать дублирование данных о подключении к базе в  .env файле symfony4 проекта.

```
#.env
DB_NAME=storage
DB_USERNAME=nds
DB_PASSWORD=123456

DATABASE_URL=mysql://nds:123456@storage:3306/storage
```

Структура каталогов:

```
app
  vendor
  ...
  .env
docker
  php
  nginx
docker-compose.yml
```

В docker-compose.yml задаю параметры подключения по ENV-ам:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: storage
    env_file:
      - ./app/.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если верить [документации](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file) надо указать файл с определением переменнымых окружения, а не каталог, где его искать. При этом путь к файлу должен быть относительно docker-compose.yml.
Следовательно для того, чтобы переиспользовать файл переменных окружения необходимо исправить на следующий вид

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: storage
    env_file:
      - ./app/.env
```

**UPDATE 1:**
В свете уточнений вопроса можно предложить вариант с использованием переменных окружения в момент использования docker-compose.

Что то вроде этого:
В файл `./app/params` пишем

```
export DB_USERNAME=myuser
export DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
export DB_NAME=mydb
```

docker-compose.yml будет иметь вид:

```
  app:
    image: app_image:1.2.3
    container_name: application
  environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
    - MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: storage
  environment:
    - DATABASE_URL: mysql://${DB_USERNAME}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_NAME}:3306/storage
    - MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
    - MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
```

Тогда запуск контейнеров можно написать так:

```
source ./app/params && docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Согласен с вами, но вопрос не в этом. В файле /app/.env дублирование параметров подключения к базе, т.е. я прописываю параметры в DATABASE_URL и дополнительно приходится прописывать DB_NAME,  DB_USERNAME и DB_PASSWORD.

Comment: Проблема актуальна для symfony, т.к. он требует, чтоб параметры подключения к базе прописывались в DATABASE_URL

Comment: да упутил этот момент. Тогда только через установку переменных окружения при самом запуске docker-compose. То есть как то так export DB_USERNAME=myuser; export DB_PASSWORD=mypassword; export DB_NAME=mydb; docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d. Тогда эти переменные можно использовать при определении переменных окружения контейнеров

Comment: Странное поведение обнаружил. На одном ПК(работа) в docker-compose.yml я могу свободно прописать, что-то типо ${VAR_ENV} и он достанет ее из .env и подставит ее значение куда нужно. На другом ПК(дома) я получаю ошибку: WARNING: The VAR_ENV variable is not set.(т.е. чтоб устранить это мне нужно сделать как вы в ответе указали) В чем может быть причина? разные версии docker-compose или самого докера?

Comment: На предыдущий вопрос ответ нашел - docker-compose тянет переменные окружения из рядом лежащего .end, а я пытался затянуть их из другой директории.